# android anr error Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010}

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, mutex

i trying to fix this errors
this error occur after adding fcm 17.+.+~18.0.0
in previous version, this anr error not occur
could i know why did this error occur?
this is main thread code
p.s) i'm using navermap sdk,too

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x76024db0 self=0x7e75814c00
  | sysTid=11665 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7efb8be548
  | state=S schedstat=( 113364872507 54406457631 191892 ) utm=7848 stm=3488 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fd7d7f000-0x7fd7d81000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=

  #00  pc 000000000001f2ac  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)

  #01  pc 00000000000228f4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__futex_wait_ex(void volatile*, bool, int, bool, timespec const*)+140)

  #02  pc 000000000009246c  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_cond_wait+60)

  #03  pc 00000000006c0734  /data/app/com.parkingbrother.parkingbrother-6hDptlHuJuICXkJB1RjLpg==/lib/arm64/libnavermap.so (std::__ndk1::condition_variable::wait(std::__ndk1::unique_lock<std::__ndk1::mutex>&)+20)

  #04  pc 00000000006c15c8  /data/app/com.parkingbrother.parkingbrother-6hDptlHuJuICXkJB1RjLpg==/lib/arm64/libnavermap.so (std::__ndk1::__assoc_sub_state::wait()+84)

  #05  pc 00000000004adcc0  /data/app/com.parkingbrother.parkingbrother-6hDptlHuJuICXkJB1RjLpg==/lib/arm64/libnavermap.so (???)

  #06  pc 0000000000095d38  /data/app/com.parkingbrother.parkingbrother-6hDptlHuJuICXkJB1RjLpg==/lib/arm64/libnavermap.so (???)

  #07  pc 0000000000095efc  /data/app/com.parkingbrother.parkingbrother-6hDptlHuJuICXkJB1RjLpg==/lib/arm64/libnavermap.so (???)

  #08  pc 00000000004b3a6c  /data/app/com.parkingbrother.parkingbrother-6hDptlHuJuICXkJB1RjLpg==/lib/arm64/libnavermap.so (???)

  #09  pc 00000000004b3b74  /data/app/com.parkingbrother.parkingbrother-6hDptlHuJuICXkJB1RjLpg==/lib/arm64/libnavermap.so (???)

  #10  pc 00000000004bbeec  /data/app/com.parkingbrother.parkingbrother-6hDptlHuJuICXkJB1RjLpg==/lib/arm64/libnavermap.so (???)

  #11  pc 000000000000062c  /data/app/com.parkingbrother.parkingbrother-6hDptlHuJuICXkJB1RjLpg==/oat/arm64/base.odex (deleted) (offset 3b000) (Java_com_naver_maps_map_NativeMapView_nativeDestroy__+124)
  at com.naver.maps.map.NativeMapView.nativeDestroy (Native method)
  at com.naver.maps.map.NativeMapView.d (SourceFile:119)
  at com.naver.maps.map.MapView.onDestroy (SourceFile:294)
  at com.naver.maps.map.MapFragment.onDestroyView (SourceFile:167)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performDestroyView (Fragment.java:2678)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1533)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManager.java:1784)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1852)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:3269)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy (FragmentManager.java:3260)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy (FragmentController.java:274)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy (FragmentActivity.java:419)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy (AppCompatActivity.java:210)
  at com.parkingbrother.parkingbrother.Main.MainActivity.Controller.MainActivity.onDestroy (MainActivity.java:92)
  at android.app.Activity.performDestroy (Activity.java:7410)
```